# How to access external function out of the class which will give us the count of the number of objects of the class

Tags: python

```
class Count():
    no_of_instance = 0
    def __init__(self):
        Count.no_of_instance +=1
    def get_no_of_instance(self):
        print self.no_of_instance
cobj1 = Count()
cobj2 = Count()
cobj3 = Count()
cobj1.get_no_of_instance()
```

in above code i am getting number of objects(3) by internal function. but my requirement is to get no. of object of class by external function.

Any help will be appreciable.

Comment: What exactly is an "external function"?

Comment: Like @decorator

Comment: Please update your question with an example of what you'd expect that to look like.

Comment: Write an external function out of the class which will give us the count of the number of objects of the class

Comment: Still no idea what that means. Perhaps `def foo(): return Count.no_of_instance`?

Comment: Actually question ask by a senior guys, i mention above answer that i asked in question. but he replied its wrong. That's why i am asking.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **staticmethod** to access a class variable, if you want it to be a included in your class or just simply access the variable directly.

```
class Count():
    no_of_instance = 0
    def __init__(self):
        Count.no_of_instance +=1
    @staticmethod
    def get_no_of_instance():
        print Count.no_of_instance

cobj1 = Count()
cobj2 = Count()
cobj3 = Count()

def get_count():
    return Count.get_no_of_instance()

get_count()
>>> 3
```

Note that I'm calling a function on the class itself, just wrapped in another function. Or you can print the class attribute directly, which will give me the same output:

```
print Count.no_of_instance
3
```